# Ruby parsing HTTPresponse with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Parsing HTTPresponse with Nokogiri

Hi, I am having trouble parsing HTTPresponse objects with Nokogiri.

I use this function to fetch a website here:

## fetch a link

```
def fetch(uri_str, limit = 10)
   
  
  # You should choose better exception.
  raise ArgumentError, 'HTTP redirect too deep' if limit == 0
  
  url = URI.parse(URI.encode(uri_str.strip))
  puts url
  
  #get path
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path,headers)
  #start TCP/IP
  response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host,url.port) { |http|
        http.request(req)
  }
  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess
    then #print final redirect to a file
    puts "this is location" + uri_str
    puts "this is the host #{url.host}"
    puts "this is the path #{url.path}"
    
    return response
    # if you get a 302 response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection 
    then 
    puts "this is redirect" + response['location']
    return fetch(response['location'],aFile, limit - 1)
  else
    response.error!
  end
end




            html = fetch("http://www.somewebsite.com/hahaha/")
            puts html
            noko = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
```

When I do this html prints a whole bunch of gibberish and
Nokogiri complains that "node_set must be a Nokogiri::XML::NOdeset

If anyone could offer help it would be quite appreciated

Comment: You should use mechanize instead of this hot mess. It takes care of redirects and deals with encodings for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing. Your `fetch` method returns a `Net::HTTPResponse` object and not just the body. You should provide the body to Nokogiri.

```
response = fetch("http://www.somewebsite.com/hahaha/")
puts response.body
noko = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
```

I've updated your script so it's runnable (bellow). A couple of things were undefined.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'net/http'

def fetch(uri_str, limit = 10)
  # You should choose better exception.
  raise ArgumentError, 'HTTP redirect too deep' if limit == 0

  url = URI.parse(URI.encode(uri_str.strip))
  puts url

  #get path
  headers = {}
  req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path,headers)
  #start TCP/IP
  response = Net::HTTP.start(url.host,url.port) { |http|
        http.request(req)
  }

  case response
  when Net::HTTPSuccess
    then #print final redirect to a file
    puts "this is location" + uri_str
    puts "this is the host #{url.host}"
    puts "this is the path #{url.path}"

    return response
    # if you get a 302 response
  when Net::HTTPRedirection
    then
    puts "this is redirect" + response['location']
    return fetch(response['location'], limit-1)
  else
    response.error!
  end
end

response = fetch("http://www.google.com/")
puts response
noko = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
puts noko
```

The script gives no error and prints the content. You may be getting Nokogiri error due to the content you're receiving. One common problem I've encountered with Nokogiri is character encoding. Without the exact error it's impossible to tell what's going on.

I'd recommnend looking at the following StackOverflow Questions

[ruby 1.9: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2982677/ruby-1-9-invalid-byte-sequence-in-utf-8)  (specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8873922/68554))

[How to convert a Net::HTTP response to a certain encoding in Ruby 1.9.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207335/how-to-convert-a-nethttp-response-to-a-certain-encoding-in-ruby-1-9-1)

Comment: Thanks a lot Mr.Simard, I'll look up the character encoding.

Comment: How can I see a more verbose debug messages? The only error Nokogiri is giving me is this node_set has to be a Nokogiri::XML::Nodeset

Comment: Ok, I did script.rb -d and this is the output:YPscraper.rb:103: warning: (...) interpreted as grouped expression
script.rb:118: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'begin' at 87
YPscraper.rb:119: warning: mismatched indentations at 'end' with 'for' at 83
Exception `LoadError' at C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_req
uire.rb:36 - cannot load such file -- nokogiriException `ArgumentError' at script.rb:102 - node_set must be a Nokogiri::XML
::NodeSet
node_set must be a Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet

Comment: It really seem like Nokogiri does not like the content you receive. I'd suggest saving it to a file and inspecting it.

Comment: That's what I did. On the surface it seems like a perfectly normal html file, it opens in the Chrome normally , the file declares that its encoding is UTF-8...

Comment: Which version of Nokogiri are you using? which version of ruby? Can you disclose the URL that's causing the problem?

Comment: Hi, Pierre-Luc, I've resolved the problem yesterday

basically I did something like this: 

page = Nokogiri::HTML(response.body)
    page.xpath("//div[(position()=1 and @class='listing_content')]/div/div/h3/a/text()")
    puts "this is name"
    puts name
    #Get Business phone
    phone = page.xpath("//div[@class='listing_content']//span[@class='business-phone phone']/text()")
    puts "this is phone"
    puts phone
aFile.syswrite(noko + " " +  phone)

and apparently syswrite didn't like the attempt at concatenation  Thanks for your help.If you have any more comments, that always welcome.