# How can you set the encoding on a Net::HTTP response if you read it in chunks?

Tags: ruby, character-encoding

Is it possible to force an encoding on a `Net::HTTP` response read using `read_body`? I know that it is possible to [call `force_encoding` on the `response.body` itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207335/how-to-convert-a-nethttp-response-to-a-certain-encoding-in-ruby-1-9-1) but that means you have to read the whole response in and loses the benefit of reading it in pieces.

I'm reading a csv file from a uri (I don't want to parse the CSV just yet) and writing it to a file locally:

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri)

  http.request request do |response|
    File.open(target_file, 'w') do |f|
      response.read_body do |chunk|
        f.write(chunk)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The content is encoded as ISO-8859-1 but `Net::HTTP` treats it as ASCII 8BIT.

(I've worked round the problem by writing it out as binary and dealing with the encoding later)

Comment: In general the chunk boundaries could end up splitting multibyte characters. Writing out the data as is seems the right thing to do to me.

Comment: Yeah, I was a bit nervous about chunking across the middle of a character. I'd hoped that setting the encoding would prevent that too.

Comment: Encoding is important if you're treating the data as text. It's meaningless if you're treating the data as binary.